# Android updating fragments from a new activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a MainFragmentActivity which hosts like 4 fragments in it, lets call them A,B,C,D.
Inside fragment A, I have two child fragments with a view pager, lets call them X,Y.
When I click some button in fragment X, it will open a new activity and do some database updates. Now when I finish this new activity, some data in fragment X should be updated from database.

What i tried is, do this stuff in onResume of fragment X. It works fine though.

But i dont know whether this is the right approach to do this. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: `ContentProvider` and `CursorLoader`s ... i'm using 'em and i have no problem with data refreshing ...

Comment: @Selvin Can u please tell couple of lines more abt how doing this, Like after finishing the new activity, what to do next?

Comment: I am aware of both ContentProvider and CursorLoader. Please tell how the control flow shud be.

Comment: ANDROID_SDK\samples\android-16\NotePad ... you don't need to do anything ... just use `getContentResolver().update(uri, ...)` to update then all `Loader`s connected with this `uri` will be refreshed ...

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that `onResume` will be called more times than you expect, which will result in more database accesses than needed.

As for me, a better approach would be using [setResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29) and [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) methods.

---

More on [Getting a result from an activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)